# sseStream.write is not working in production

Tags: javascript, node.js, streaming

I am collecting a streaming response and sending it to the frontend. I have doubled checked, response from streaming response and it is definitely a stream.

But for some reason, the response from backend is piling up everything and sending it in one go. It's even waiting for the reader.on('end') event. What am I doing wrong here?

Everything, including the streaming, is working properly on localhost.

```
const response = getStreamingResponse()

    const sseStream = new SseStream(req);
    sseStream.pipe(res);

    const reader = response.body;
    let answer = "";

    reader.on('data', (data: any) => {
      let decoded = new TextDecoder().decode(data);
      answer += decoded

      sseStream.write({ data });
    });

  reader.on('end', async () => {
      console.log("End of stream");


//I have other fns like saving to Database here and then 

  const buffer = Buffer.from(savedConversation?._id, "utf-8");
  res.write(`conversationId: ${buffer.toString()}\n\n`);
  sseStream.end();

}
```

Response send from server looks like this

```
:ok

data: {"type":"Buffer","data":[84,104,105,115,32,105,115,32,97,32,116,101,115,116,32,114,101,115,112,111,110,115,101,46,32]}


data: {"type":"Buffer","data":[84,104,105,115,32,105,115,32,97,32,116,101,115,116,32,114,101,115,112,111,110,115,101,46,32]}


data: {"type":"Buffer","data":[84,104,105,115,32,105,115,32,97,32,116,101,115,116,32,114,101,115,112,111,110,115,101,46,32]}


data: {"type":"Buffer","data":[84,104,105,115,32,105,115,32,97,32,116,101,115,116,32,114,101,115,112,111,110,115,101,46,32]}


data: {"type":"Buffer","data":[84,104,105,115,32,105,115,32,97,32,116,101,115,116,32,114,101,115,112,111,110,115,101,46,32]}


conversationId: 647719ed65f98063de96b9a5
```